# Webmaster showing unsupported file as error in sitemap

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap

In my website i have big sitemap. So i compressed t using Gzip. and the format of sitemap is like

[image]
[image]

When i submit this sitemap to webmaster it shows unsupported file.

Comment: I would ask you how you compressed the file, what tool did you use and what OS. For example, it may be that *X* product on Windows does not create the .gz file format that is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your sitemap within the sitemap is damaged or not a gzip as it fails 2/3 of my tests.

Test 1/3: winrar - `No errors found during test operation`

Test 2/3: tar

```
bybe@ubuntu:~$ tar -tzf test.gz > /dev/null
bybe@ubuntu:~$ tar -tzf sitemapCP38.xml.gz > /dev/null
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Test 3/3: gunzip

```
bybe@ubuntu:~$ gunzip -c sitemapCP38.xml.gz | tar t > /dev/null
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```